# APOPT is finding a better local minimum to a MINLP problem when I use fewer nlp iterations. I was expecting the opposite result, what am I missing?

Tags: gekko

I have the following boolean and continuous variables, where only some of the 'percents' have a status of 1.

```
status[i] = m.Array(m.Var, p, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
percent[i] = m.Array(m.FV, p, value=1, lb=0.6, ub=1.1)
```

I've used some intermediaries that use the min2 option that are fed into my contraint equation.

My objective is a linear summation of status, percent and a constant.

I am using the following solver options:

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    # Options
    m.options.SOLVER = 1
    m.options.LINEAR = 0

    # optional solver settings with APOPT
    m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01',
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 500',
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0',
                    'minlp_interger_leaves = 0',
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.01',
                    'minlp_print_level 2'
                    ]
```

My returned objective is: **2140.05**, none of the constraints are violated and the solution is very good. However, by reducing the 'nlp_maximum_iterations' to 10, I can get an even better solution of **2138.67**.

I would expect that my minimum would improve with increasing iterations. My plan was to find a balance between runtime and optimal cost, with the expectation that a long runtime would lead to a solution close to the global minimum, that I could use as a baseline.

In my testing of the problem, it seems that the nlp_max_iterations is the controlling factor on weather or not it finds the lower of the two costs. minlp_maximum_iterations, minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol,and minlp_gap_tol, did not seem to have an affect on the solution.

Any explanation of this behavior would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Consider editing your title to be more concise and specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few tips that may help:

- Use `min3` instead of `min2`. This uses a binary variable form instead of the MPCC form that can give false solutions.
- APOPT should keep the best integer solution and return that if it reaches maximum iterations. Is the solution with objective `2138.67` an integer solution?
- If it is a maximization problem then `2140.05` would be a better solution. Could you confirm that you are using `m.Minimize()` instead of `m.Maximize()`?

The APOPT solver uses a [branch and bound method](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/DiscreteOptimization) that solves Nonlinear Programming (NLP) problems while successively bounding variables at integer constraints. Here are [methods for declaring binary, integer, and special ordered sets](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/IntegerBinaryVariables).

Comment: It appears that switching from min2 to min3 solved the issue. I will confirm that is the case with some more testing. Both solutions returned were integer solutions. Both solutions were returned with a success message from the solver. The solver was using the default of minimize and the solution matched my expectations (i.e. clearly a local minimum for the problem).

Comment: I'm glad it helped to switch to `min3`. If you want to check the `min2` solution, I'd recommend that you verify that each equation is satisfied. I typically don't use the `min2`, `sign2`, `max2`, `if2`, or other MPCC functions unless there are no competing objectives that can sometimes lead to false solutions.

Comment: One issue that I noticed with the min function is that it creates a 'helper variable' and 2 constraints to obtain a minimum. The helper variable is subject to the same integer tolerances, letting the min function return a variable up to 1% off the input variable (using the default tolerance). If there is an inequality constraint that has a min/max function it can fudge a solution by 1% regardless of the inequality constraint tolerance.

Comment: Here is more information on how those functions work. https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions Does it help to set the default tolerance tighter such as 'minlp_integer_tol 0.0001'?